# Mathematical Equation in Apache Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Can anyone help me convert the below equation to Pig?

```
((score + score2)/3)*(1+(5/(10*sqrt(power((score - score2),2)+1))))​
```

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by convert? what have you tried?

Comment: this is a postgre's query,  i tried in hive it's working but in hive it says, ERROR 1070: Could not resolve power using imports: [, java.lang., org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.im
pl.builtin.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya you can do this in Pig.  You'll need the path to your `piggybank.jar`.  There are a bunch of math functions in there.  It is usually in the `lib` directory wherever you have pig installed.  So, mine is in `/usr/local/pig/lib/piggybank.jar`.  Here are the [docs](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/evaluation/math/package-summary.html) for all the functions (I think that is the link to the older version of Pig but it should be okay for reference to this question).  I guess you'll have some relation with the variables  `score` and `score2` in it.  We'll call the relation `A`.

```
REGISTER '/path/to/pig/piggybank.jar'
DEFINE SQRT org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.math.SQRT;
DEFINE POW org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.math.POW;

/**
 * You'll probably want to import some data here
 */

B = FOREACH A GENERATE ((score + score2)/3)*(1+(5/(10*SQRT(1+POW((score - score2), 2)))));
```

Comment: Hey thank's man this is what i exactly tried and it worked.! :D